# How to contantly report data back with external javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, external

How do services such as Clicktale (and other heatmapping sites) report time on page and mouse movements etc back to their servers using one javascript file?

I understand Google Analytics does it via a gif image but that is only called once. How do you constantly send data back? (Can't use ajax because of cross site scripting limitations).

Cheers, Tim

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), it's an event driven javascript I/O library. Some impressive things have been done with it. See [this example](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/experimenting-with-node-js/) which tracks mouse movements and distributes the activity.

Comment: Look interesting, though requires the visitors browsers to use web sockets, would like something more cross compatible.